# Is there any way in TortoiseSVN to incrementally build my commit?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Time and again, I am facing the situation in TortoiseSVN that I have to commit files that are widely spread across a huge repository. As this usually happens while I'm in the middle of several tasks (meaning that there are plenty of other changed files in my working copy that I do not want to commit yet), and the working copy also contains plenty of unversioned, un-ignored files for various reasons, selecting the files I want to commit is a very tedious task<sup>1</sup>.

**Can I somehow build the list of files to build my commit list incrementally, e.g. by opening the *Commit* dialog box several times in different subdirectories (preferrably while using the *Restore after commit* feature on some of the files), where I can easily find and select the individual files to commit?**

Solutions I have considered:

- **SVN CLI:** Granted, this would be trivial via the SVN command line interface. I could just add the files to commit to a batch file. This solution comes with its own caveats, of course, which include less Explorer integration (meaning that the visual file icon markings may not be updated right away) and the fact that writing/copy-pasting file paths and names into a text editor is error-prone in its own right.
- **Change lists:** This looked promising at first, until I realized that I seem to be able to add additional files to a change list started in one directory only in its ancestor directories; the change list menu does not show the respective change list e.g. in sibling directories to the one where the first files were added. (But maybe there is a solution to declare the change list globally, for the entire working copy?)
- **Branches:** At first glance, it seems like this could be a use case for branches. However, the changes that I do not want to commit yet often do not belong to unrelated tasks. As such, many of the changed files that I do not wish to commit yet would likely reside in the same branch.
- **Sorting the Files:** Doesn't really help. Due to the way our files are named, even though I may be doing a very regular change (e.g. an analogous change to each file with a specific function across 20 modules), the affected file names all start differently (they just *end* the same, but I don't see any way to sort the list based upon that criterion).
- **Shelving:** [Shelving](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-shelving.html) is another promising feature. Still, putting everything that I don't need right now on a shelf sounds rather tedious again. It appears I am looking for the *opposite* of shelving, or a shelf from which I can directly commit (which appears not to be possible with the current Shelving feature as of v1.11).

<sup>1</sup>: I am primarily referring to the fact that I have to browse a long list and find the specific files I would like to commit. The fact that with one misplaced click, my entire previous selection may be removed again adds insult to injury.

Comment: Try to work with branches http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.using.html

Comment: @Hackerman: Thanks for the suggestion; I have added branches to the list of considered solutions.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't open up the commit dialog from the root of your working copy, you should be able to filter what files/folders you want to commit very easily. For example if your checkout folder is:

```
C:/MyProject
|_FolderA
|_FolderB
|_FolderC
|_FolderD
```

If you're working in `FolderA` but want to commit your files to `FolderB` and `FolderC` you can quite literally just **Ctrl+Left Click** both `FolderB` and `FolderC`, **Right Click** on one of the selected items, and then select  **SVN Commit...**.

You should only see files relevant to the folders you want to commit. Also, at the bottom of each commit log, there's a checkbox that says "Show unversioned files", and you can remove all of the files that you have not specifically **SVN Add**ed to your working copy.

The process of **SVN Add**ing can follow the same process of Shift or Ctrl + Left Clicking all of the items you want (or just right clicking on a folder and selecting **TortoiseSVN > Add...** and selecting all the items in the list that you're looking to "prepare" for a commit.

Comment: Unfortunately, the extreme case (that I encounter with a certain frequency) is that I need to commit one file from each of the directories `FolderA`, `FolderB`, `FolderC`, and `FolderD`, with each of these containing loads of other files. This could be a good solution if it were possible to multi-select in the directory tree, but it seems it isn't in Windows Explorer.

Comment: Well if your have a local folder containg the working copy of FolderA, FolderB, FolderC and FolderD, you can multi-select the 4 folders by "CTRL+left click". So you can then right-click, select the commit menu, and select which files you want to commit in one time.

Comment: @LaurentH.: Yes, but then I can just as well select the root folder, as I'm going to get all the files from all the subdirectories in the commit dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

In TortoiseSVN, you can use `changelists`.
In the commit dialog, select the files that belong to one specific change, right-click and select "`Move to changelist->new changelist`", then enter a name for that changelist.
Now the commit dialog groups those files.

When you later want to commit such a changelist, just click the group header to check all the files in it.
And the checkbox "Keep changelists" at the bottom left of the commit dialog indicates whether the changelist should be removed after the commit.

Comment: I already mentioned that option in the question, including an aspect that makes this option somewhat useless for the issue presented. Am I maybe missing something about the feature, and could you address that point explicitly in the answer, please?

Comment: if the changelist you've created isn't shown in other folders, you can add files to it by creating a new one with the same name.